# Javascript foreach and for loop always loop once only when do array.push

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Javascript code loop once only when do array.push when put console.log(odgovor) it display everything good

```
getTacni() {
    this.storageService.getQuestions().then(items => {
      let odgovori: { id: number; answer: number }[] = [];
      let odgovor: { id: number; answer: number } = { id: null, answer: null };
      for (let i of items) {
        odgovor.id = i.id;
        odgovor.answer = i.tacan;
        console.log(odgovor);
      }
    });
  }
```

FAIL every element in odgovori is same

```
getTacni() {
    this.storageService.getQuestions().then(items => {
      let odgovori: { id: number; answer: number }[] = [];
      let odgovor: { id: number; answer: number } = { id: null, answer: null };
      for (let i of items) {
        odgovor.id = i.id;
        odgovor.answer = i.tacan;
        odgovori.push(odgovor);
      }
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In both snippets, you've only created one object in memory, which you proceed to mutate many times - create each object inside the loop instead:

```
getTacni() {
  this.storageService.getQuestions().then(items => {
    const odgovori: { id: number; answer: number }[] = [];
    for (let i of items) {
      const odgovor: { id: number; answer: number } = { id: i.id, answer: i.tacan };
      odgovori.push(odgovor);
    }
  });
}
```

You also might consider using `.map`, which is a concise, functional, and readable way to transform every element of one array into another:

```
getTacni() {
  this.storageService.getQuestions().then(items => {
    const odgovor = items.map(({ id, tacan }) => ({ id, answer: tacan }));
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
getTacni() {
  this.storageService.getQuestions().then(items => {
    const odgovori: { id: number; answer: number }[] = [];
    for (let i of items) {
      odgovori.push({ id: i.id, answer: i.tacan });
    }
  });
}
```